# Least Squares Approximation for FIR Filter Design

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, least-squares

Following this [paper](https://cnx.org/contents/6x7LNQOp@7/Linear-Phase-Fir-Filter-Design) , I am trying to make a least-squares algorithm in MATLAB, but for type I (I know about `firls()`).

```
N = 41;
M = (N-1)/2;

wp=0.2;
ws = 0.4;
K = 2;
fp = wp/2;
fs = ws/2;
q= [fp+K*(1-fs), (fp*sinc(fp*[1:2*M])-K*fs*sinc(fs*[1:2*M]))];
Q1 = toeplitz(q([0:M]+1));
Q2 = hankel(q([0:M]+1),q([M:2*M]+1));
Q = (Q1 + Q2)/2;
b = fp*sinc(fp*[0:M]');
a = Q\b;
h = [a(M+1:-1:2)/2; a(1); a(2:M)/2]
```

- How to find the design FIR filter if the desired  response :
  [image]
- How to find the group delay in this case response in matlab

Comment: See these links: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40754/least-squares-fir-for-type-ii/40790#40790 , and https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?51310 . They are for Octave, but they should work in Matlab, too. (Did you also mean you need it for type `II`, instead of `I`? I'm asking because the paper already is for type `I`.)

Comment: yes it is for type I but the problem in the desired response, in paper the passe band(pb) is between [0 w0] and the stop band(sb) [w0 pi],how to do in case if pb=[-wp1  wp2 ] ,the sb1=[-pi   ws1] and sb2=[ws2   pi].

Comment: Ah, I see now. This paper's LS algorithm deals without a specified transition band (what you want with separate `wp` and `ws`, instead of a single `wc`), but there are some other papers where you can specify it: search for "constrained least squares", and you should find other papers from Selesnick and Burrus (and probably others). Still, this paper will get you the desired `wp` and ws` the way it's calculated, but you got something wrong in there: `fp=/=wp/2`, but `fp=wp/pi`. It's possible you got wrong results because of this.

Comment: In the 'constrained least squares FIR filter' must be used 'fircls',so use the functions 'fdesign.bandpass' and 'design'

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,but in the 'constrained least squares FIR filter' must be used 'fircls',so use the functions 'fdesign.bandpass' and 'design' ,how to use it in this program matlab.